# Any character match not working in Apache mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a URL on a website using Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

I have the following lines in a `.htaccess` file, which is in a folder `foo` in the server's root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The idea is that everything after `foo/` in the URL `http://abc.example.com/foo/bar` is extracted and rewritten to `http://abc.example.com/foo/index.php?id=bar`, which I thought should be pretty straightforward - this isn't my first time using `mod_rewrite`.

I've tested this successfully on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be, however, I'm finding that on my server it will only work if I use `[a-z]+` instead of the wildcard `.+` in the rule. Otherwise the `id` parameter returns `index.php`.

Is there a problem with my rule declaration? If not, what configuration could be causing this behaviour, and how can I override it?

Comment: just a friendly note, it is called mod_rewrite.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth a shot in case other rewrites are interefering, or by any chance you are rewriting into index.php by accident:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index.php)(.*) index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was caused by  `/foo/bar` was being rewritten to `/foo/index.php?id=bar`, which was then being rewritten to `/foo/index.pnp?id=index.php`. The `QSA` flag suggested in [another answer](/a/40137228/3803805) also fixes this, but doesn't get to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Problem might be related to Query string.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa